# _Actual_ Twitter format for hashtags? Not your regex, not his code-- the actual one?

Tags: regex, parsing, twitter, bnf, hashtag

### Update: Use Twitter's Entities if you can- they figured it out for you as well as other items. My case is that I just have the tweet without entities and all the extra metadata

I've spent what I consider an unreasonable amount of time trying to find the *actual* format for hashtags.

As far as my searching can tell- Twitter has not published one.

I know that many people have come up with regex's to parse them, however, your lib's regex is not my lib's regex and maybe I don't like yours anyway.

**So I'm asking- is there any actual official spec?** I don't want a regex answer, I want a BNF or something similar. Or minimally- a complete list of delimiters.

*Additional difficulty points*- grabbing them from random unicode messages (non-English) text is important too.

Note: I'm quite aware of entities and they aren't applicable to my case (months of twitter messages stored in a db).

Comment: Isn't it just any series of non-whitespace characters following a #? I don't think there is a formal grammar, especially not one which couldn't be parsed by a regex. It isn't html...

Comment: @stimms NO! Twitter has their own way of detecting hash tags. Have a look at Manu's answer. It's quite complex, as it deals with many different unicode scripts.

Comment: @stimms The answer is to use their entities. Before they added them, this was a very relevant question- now it's trivial to determine what's what.

Comment: Were you able to find a signle regex in js to handle this? I cant find it

Comment: @ Noitidart The answer is- don't do it. Don't. Use the Entities that come with the message. During the timeframe I was concerned with this question, the Entities and related data didn't exist or wheren't commonly implemented (not sure which). If you have a body of existing tweets without that extra data, I'd recommend hacking your own algorithm together for the bulk of the ones you care about and ignoring edge-cases. If you're using Java, I was able to find a regex in their public code, but I don't think it covers every case- ie- international messages, etc.

Answer (score 20):

From the starting point of [twitter's support](http://support.twitter.com/groups/32-something-s-not-working/topics/119-tweet-dm-problems/articles/370610-my-hashtags-or-replies-aren-t-working) the basic rules seems to be that hashtags must be preceded by a space and stop on any whitespace or punctuation.

---

Quote from Twitter's support:

Check your hashtags for the following:

- Is there any symbol in or after the hashtag?

  - If you write #noican't, your message will be categorized under #noican. Punctuation marks ( , . ; ' ? ! etc.) will end your hashtag wherever punctuation occurs.
- Is there any letter preceding the #symbol?

  - If you write 23#idoittoo or word#idoittoo, your Tweets will not show in searches for the hashtag #idoittoo. Hashtags will not work with letters or numbers in front of the # symbol. The # symbol must have a space directly in front of it in order for it to show correctly in searches.

---

Therefore, the initial token is `#` preceded by a space, and the terminator is any whitespace or punctuation. The "*etc*" in their list of punctuation (" *, . ; ' ? ! etc.*") is annoying, but I'll keep digging and see if I can find something authoritative on what else counts as punctuation.

After digging around a while, I found some interesting blog articles by Terence Eden ([Hashtags and Implicit Knowledge](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2010/02/hashtags-and-implicit-knowledge/), [Hashtag Standards](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2010/02/hashtag-standards/)) that provide evidence that Twitter doesn't even have a standard, given that the software it develops on different platforms seems to have different rules of what constitutes a hashtag.

It also provided a link to the Twitter Conformance Library, which has [twitter / twitter-text-conformance / autolink.yml](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/conformance/autolink.yml). The `hashtag` section in [autolink.yml](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/conformance/autolink.yml) has many cases matching the above rules, but also some that violate them are are still supposed to be autolinked. Some examples:

```
- description: "DO NOT Autolink all-numeric hashtags"
  text: "text #1234"
  expected: "text #1234"

- description: "Autolink hashtag preceded by a period"
  text: "text.#hashtag"
  expected: "text.<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23hashtag\" title=\"#hashtag\" class=\"tweet-url hashtag\">#hashtag</a>"

- description: "Autolink hashtag with full-width hash (U+FF03)"
  text: "＃hashtag"
  expected: "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23hashtag\" title=\"#hashtag\" class=\"tweet-url hashtag\">＃hashtag</a>"
```

Those are just a few examples that don't match the basic rules given in the first support article, and unfortunately the `yml` is full of other examples as well.

Comment: In regex terms, /(?<= )#\w+/ Worth noting that \w matches underscores, but underscores do appear to be allowed in hashtags.

Comment: @Asmor: Based on how the official Twitter.app for Mac highlights it, I think it's more like `/(?<!\w)#\w+/`

Comment: Thanks- that's about the conclusion I came to- there isn't any totally formal spec for it.

Comment: Tweets can be proceeded by a space *or* a hashtag (i.e. ####hey, is parsed as #hey), but they cannot proceed *and* end with a hashtag, (i.e. #hey# is an invalid tag)

Answer (score 18):

There is in fact an official specification for hashtags.  Twitter accepts only a subset of Unicode expressions for the hashtag syntax.  Here is the regular expression to recognize all valid Hashtags used on Twitter (pulled from their own sourcecode.)

To see how it's generated see [the source code of twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/twitter-text.js).

```
/(#|＃)([a-z0-9_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f]*[a-z_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f][a-z0-9_\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff\u0100-\u024f\u0253-\u0254\u0256-\u0257\u0300-\u036f\u1e00-\u1eff\u0400-\u04ff\u0500-\u0527\u2de0-\u2dff\ua640-\ua69f\u0591-\u05bf\u05c1-\u05c2\u05c4-\u05c5\u05d0-\u05ea\u05f0-\u05f4\ufb12-\ufb28\ufb2a-\ufb36\ufb38-\ufb3c\ufb40-\ufb41\ufb43-\ufb44\ufb46-\ufb4f\u0610-\u061a\u0620-\u065f\u066e-\u06d3\u06d5-\u06dc\u06de-\u06e8\u06ea-\u06ef\u06fa-\u06fc\u0750-\u077f\u08a2-\u08ac\u08e4-\u08fe\ufb50-\ufbb1\ufbd3-\ufd3d\ufd50-\ufd8f\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufdf0-\ufdfb\ufe70-\ufe74\ufe76-\ufefc\u200c-\u200c\u0e01-\u0e3a\u0e40-\u0e4e\u1100-\u11ff\u3130-\u3185\ua960-\ua97f\uac00-\ud7af\ud7b0-\ud7ff\uffa1-\uffdc\u30a1-\u30fa\u30fc-\u30fe\uff66-\uff9f\uff10-\uff19\uff21-\uff3a\uff41-\uff5a\u3041-\u3096\u3099-\u309e\u3400-\u4dbf\u4e00-\u9fff\u20000-\u2a6df\u2a700-\u2b73f\u2b740-\u2b81f\u2f800-\u2fa1f]*)/gi
```

Comment: It does match `#1a2@r^@@3` now I'm curious if it's a valid hashtag

Comment: In the ruby version it only matches `#1a2`, not the rest. See https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/rb/lib/twitter-text/regex.rb

Answer (score 5):

I found this : ["Need help parsing tweet text?", on dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-url-wrapper)

> Take a look on the Twitter text processing library we’re using for
>   auto linking and extraction of usernames, lists & hashtags.

(there's [ruby](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/rb), [java](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/java) and [javascript](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js) librairies)

They are quite enormous, as twitter must take into account every possible case.

Answer (score 3):

this is what I use, the closest i get:

```
/#(\w*[0-9a-zA-Z]+\w*[0-9a-zA-Z])/g
```

[link of the hashtag Regex to test](https://regex101.com/r/pI7hE4/5)

[image: CavalcanteLeo]

Comment: This is woefully incomplete as it ignores all the Latin/foreign characters. See the post by @user1122127 above.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter entity parsing libraries are available here: https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text

Comment: Problem with them is that if it's not in your language, conversion can be nontrivial, esp wrt regex's.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the official Twitter client for Mac highlights hashtags, I suspect the rule is any sequence of contiguous letters, numbers, or underlines following a hash. In other words, it's as simple as the regex `/#\w+/` (assuming a unicode-aware regex engine).

Answer (score 0):

`/\B(?:#|＃)((?![\p{N}_]+(?:$|\b|\s))(?:[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]{1,60}))/ug`

- allow any language characters or characters with numbers or `_`.
- numbers alone or numbers with `_`  are not allowed.

It's unicode regex, so if you are using Python, you may need to install [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

to test it https://regex101.com/r/NLHUQh/1