# How do you store text from a .txt file into a cell array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, twitter, hashtag

For this project I am doing, I have to analyze tweets off of a company's twitter page. I took the last thirty tweets of this company, and I put it into a .txt document, where each line is a different tweet. I am supposed to store all of the hashtags in a cell array, and then print out these hashtags to the command window. (The hashtags are supposed to include the phrase or words inside the hashtags as well. for example, #matlab #programming #stackoverflow.) I am really confused on how I would store them into a cell array. This is the code, that I have so far. All it does is count the number of hashtags in the entire file.

```
%% Collecting the hashtags
fid=fopen('twitter.txt');
hashtag=0
nextLine=(fgetl(fid));
while ischar(nextLine)
if regexp(nextLine,'#')
    hashtag=hashtag+length(regexp(nextLine,'#'));
end
nextLine=(fgetl(fid));
end
```

Is there a way to just take the file contents and store it into a cell array with a command, or would I have to manually copy and paste the entire content of the file into something like the variable below and then use a while loop to just access the cell array and use fprintf to print each hashtag out?

```
hashtagArray={'#...','#..',..}
```

Comment: Can you post an example file of tweets?

Comment: Hey, I tried to post a screenshot of the tweets, but stackoverflow wouldn't allow me to because I needed more experience points or something. Just think of it as a notepad document, where every tweet gets its own line. It is 30 lines long. If you still would like to see the file, I would be happy to email it to you.

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains only the text from tweets, load the whole thing into a cell array with textscan (tested with a random selection of made up tweets):

```
fid=fopen('twitter.txt');
C = textscan(fid,'%s');
C = C{1};
```

C should now be a cell array of words/hashtags (split by whitespace). We only want the hashtags:

```
k = strncmp(C, '#', 1); %looks for those with hash at the #start 
C2 = C(k);
```

Note: Officially Twitter considers either whitespace or punctuation to be the end of a hashtag (see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451846/)).  So `C2` may contain something like #noican't whereas Twitter would recognise the actual hashtag as #noican.