# Regex to find words inside a string

Tags: java, regex, linkify

Please a little help with **regex** to use as `Pattern` in *Linkify*.

I'm trying to extract *#hashtags* and *@mentions* inside a string, so I need to find words inside the string that starts with `#` and `@` (and ends with the blank of course), just in a single regex.

Inside the word, I need to admit every possible chars in any language (somewhere :) ).

Thank you.

**EDIT**

When I say *every possible chars* I'm wrong: I need anyhow to follow the same rules of twitter, so for example chars like `-` are not admitted.

Comment: Are you targetting twitter data?

Comment: @gonbe no it's just for internal use.

Comment: That's difficult to test any possible characters in any language for the internal system...

Comment: @gonbe sorry, I have not explained well. It's for internal use but rules about hashtags are the same of Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

After seeing that you want to identify hash tags according to Twitter and reading [_Actual_ Twitter format for hashtags? Not your regex, not his code-- the actual one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451846/actual-twitter-format-for-hashtags-not-your-regex-not-his-code-the-actual)

Try this pattern:

```
"^[@#]\\w+|(?<=\\s)[@#]\\w+"
```

It matches words that start with `"@"` or `"#"` that is either at the beginning of a line or is preceded by a space

Code Sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String string = "#hashtags and @mentions";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^[@#]\\w+|(?<=\\s)[@#]\\w+").matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
#hashtags
@mentions
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the Twitter rules, why not use the library from the ones who know the rules better than anyone else: [the Twitter themselves](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/java)? :-)

In case you use Gradle, you can just add `compile 'com.twitter:twitter-text:1.12.1'` to the dependencies in your Gradle file.

Or for Maven, add to pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
    <artifactId>twitter-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then in your code you can call the Twitter library like this:

```
import com.twitter.Extractor;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Extractor extractor = new Extractor();
        String text = "extracting hashtags and mentions in #java using @twitter library from @github";

        System.out.println("#hashtags:");
        for (String hashtag : extractor.extractHashtags(text)) {
            System.out.println(hashtag);
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("@mentions:");
        for (String mention : extractor.extractMentionedScreennames(text)) {
            System.out.println(mention);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex (use `\\` instead of `\` in Java:

```
/(#\S+)|(@\S+)/g
```

or

```
/([#@]\S+)/g
```

You can use also this to use `\1` substitution:

```
/.*?([#@]\S+)[^#@]*/g
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/xM4eI2/2)

and if you want to remove `#` and `@` use this:

```
/.*?[#@](\S+)[^#@]*/g
```

or

```
/.*?[#@](\S+)[^#@\-]*/g
```

---

```
String rgx = ".*?[#@](\S+)[^#@\-]*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rgx, Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Should it be `+` instead of `*`?

Comment: Also, in Java, don't use the `/` characters. In fact, since `java` is the only language tag in the question, I'd change your answer completely to use Java syntax; what you wrote is appropriate for JavaScript or Perl but not Java.  Plus I'm not sure `g` has any meaning if you're not doing a replacement.

Comment: * matches zero occurrence. E.g., '#'.

Comment: If I understand it well `/.*?[#@](\S+)[^#@\-]*/g` can help ;).

Comment: Why don't you write regex for "Pattern in Linkify"?

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio my comment here is to shA.t